# How to get the 3d coordinates of a model instance in LibGDX?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, coordinates

I want to get the 3d coordinates (as a Vector3) from my model Instances.
with the following code I can only get the original coordinates, but in the render method, my model is rotating around the Y-axis (and moving at the same time) and I want to get its coordinates each frame.

I'm using a little class created by @Xoppa :

```
public static class GameObject extends ModelInstance {
    public Vector3 center = new Vector3();
    public Vector3 dimensions = new Vector3();
    public float radius;

    public BoundingBox bounds = new BoundingBox();

    public GameObject (Model model, String rootNode, boolean mergeTransform) {
        super(model, rootNode, mergeTransform);
        calculateBoundingBox(bounds);
        bounds.getCenter(center);
        bounds.getDimensions(dimensions);
        radius = dimensions.len() / 2f;
    }
}
```

and here's my code:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);
    if (loading && manager.update()) {
        doneLoading();
    }

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    backgroundSprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

    for(GameObject instance : instances){
        instance.transform.rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0.5f);
        float x = instance.bounds.getCenterX();
        float y = instance.bounds.getCenterY();
        float z = instance.bounds.getCenterZ();
        System.out.println(x+" "+y+" "+z);
        if(isVisible(cam, instance)){
            modelBatch.begin(cam);
            modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
            modelBatch.end();
        }
    }
}
```

There's no function "getPosition" or something like that, it's all about Matrix4 and I have never had a math course about it. I'm stuck.

Comment: Here you go: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17878&p=75338#p75338

Comment: @Xoppa I followed what you did in your tutorial but it doesn't seem to work:

Comment: Here's my render method :      `for(GameObject instance : instances){
            instance.transform.rotate(new Vector3(0,1,0),0.5f);
            instance.updateTransform();
            System.out.println(instance.position);
            if(isVisible(cam, instance)){
                modelBatch.begin(cam);
                modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
                modelBatch.end();
            }
        }    and the GameObject Class:

Comment: I don't know how to format in the comment section >.< sorry for the multiple answers..

Answer (score 2):

And the GameObject Class:

```
public static class GameObject extends ModelInstance {
    public Vector3 center = new Vector3();
    public Vector3 dimensions = new Vector3();
    public float radius;
    public final Vector3 position = new Vector3();
    public final Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion();
    public final Vector3 scale = new Vector3();

    public BoundingBox bounds = new BoundingBox();

    public GameObject (Model model, String rootNode, boolean mergeTransform) {
        super(model, rootNode, mergeTransform);
        calculateBoundingBox(bounds);
        bounds.getCenter(center);
        bounds.getDimensions(dimensions);
        radius = dimensions.len() / 2f;
    }

    public void updateTransform() {
        this.transform.set(position, rotation, scale);
    }
}`
```

It only returns (0, 0, 0) and when I use the updateTransform method, it doesn't even render.

Sorry for the multiple answers. didn't know how to format in the comment section